# Calling a Delphi DLL from C# - Issues

Tags: c#, delphi, dll, interop, unmanaged

First: I read a lot of similar questions, tried a lot of different solutions, yet I couldn't achieve to work with the Delphi DLL.

The Delphi DLL provides the following method:

```pascal
procedure FetchData(var infoIn: INParameter; var infoOut: OUTParameter; var details: OUTDetails); stdcall; external DLL_Name;
```

The types are defined like this:

```pascal
type
  Info1 = record
    Param1: Byte;
    Param2: Byte;
    Param3: Byte;
    Param4: Byte;
    Param5: integer;
  end;
  PInfo1 = ^Info1;
  
  Info2 = record
    Param1: Byte;
    Param2: integer;
    Param3: integer;
    Param4: integer;
    Param5: long;
    Param6: string;
    Param7: integer;
    Param8: array [0 .. 8] of integer;
    Param9: string;
  end;
  PInfo2 = ^Info2;

  INParameter = record
    Param1: integer;
    Param2: integer;
    Param3: integer;
    Param4: Byte;
    Param5: Byte;
    Param6: Byte;
    Param7: Byte;
    Param8: Byte;
    Param9: Byte;
    Param10: Byte;
    Param11: Byte;
    Param12: Byte;
    Param13: Byte;
    Param14: Byte;
    Param15: Byte;
    Param16: Byte;
    Param17: Byte;
    Param18: Byte;
    Param19: Byte;
    Param20: Byte;
    Param21: Byte;
    Param22: Byte;
    Param23: integer;
    Param24: integer;
    Param25: Byte;
    Param26: Byte;
    Param27: Byte;
    Param28: Byte;
    Param29: Byte;
    Param30: Byte;
    Param31: Byte;
    Param32: Byte;
    Param33: integer;
    Param34: PInfo1;
    Param35: PInfo2;
  end;
  
  OUTParameter = record
    Param1: integer;
    Param2: integer;
    Param3: integer;
    Param4: integer;
    Param5: bool;
    Param6: bool;
    Param7: integer;
    Param8: integer;
    Param9: bool;
    Param10: bool;
    Param11: bool;
    Param12: bool;
    Param13: bool;
    Param14: bool;
    Param15: integer;
    Param16: integer;
    Param17: integer;
    Param18: bool;
    Param19: bool;
    Param20: integer;
  end;
  
  Pos = record
    Param1: integer;
    Param2: integer;
    Param3: Byte;
    Param4: Byte;
  end;
  
  OUTDetails = record
    Poss: array [0 .. 3, 0 .. 20] of Pos;
  end;
```

I've translated the types to C# like this:

```cs
public structure Info1
{
    public Byte Param1;
    public Byte Param2;
    public Byte Param3;
    public Byte Param4;
    public int Param5;
}
    
public structure Info2
{
    public Byte Param1;
    public int Param2;
    public int Param3;
    public int Param4;
    public long Param5;
    public string Param6;
    public int Param7;
    public int[] Param8;
    public string Param9;
}
    
public structure INParameter
{
    public int Param1;
    public int Param2;
    public int Param3;
    public Byte Param4;
    public Byte Param5;
    public Byte Param6;
    public Byte Param7;
    public Byte Param8;
    public Byte Param9;
    public Byte Param10;
    public Byte Param11;
    public Byte Param12;
    public Byte Param13;
    public Byte Param14;
    public Byte Param15;
    public Byte Param16;
    public Byte Param17;
    public Byte Param18;
    public Byte Param19;
    public Byte Param20;
    public Byte Param21;
    public Byte Param22;
    public int Param23;
    public int Param24;
    public Byte Param25;
    public Byte Param26;
    public Byte Param27;
    public Byte Param28;
    public Byte Param29;
    public Byte Param30;
    public Byte Param31;
    public Byte Param32;
    public int Param33;
    public PInfo1 Param34;
    public PInfo2 Param35;
}
    
public structure OUTParameter
{
    public int Param1;
    public int Param2;
    public int Param3;
    public int Param4;
    public bool Param5;
    public bool Param6;
    public int Param7;
    public int Param8;
    public bool Param9;
    public bool Param10;
    public bool Param11;
    public bool Param12;
    public bool Param13;
    public bool Param14;
    public int Param15;
    public int Param16;
    public int Param17;
    public bool Param18;
    public bool Param19;
    public int Param20;
}
    
public structure Pos
{
    public int Param1;
    public int Param2;
    public Byte Param3;
    public Byte Param4;
}
    
public structure Details
{
    public Pos[] Poss;
}
```

Then, in a console app, I've added the DLL extern methods definition:

```cs
[DllImport("DelphiDLL.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public static extern void FetchData(IntPtr paramIn,
                                      IntPtr paramOut,
                                      IntPtr detailsOut);
```

I tried different definitions, using:

- `ref INParameter, ref OUTParameter`
- `out OUTParameter`
- `[Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)] out OUTParameter`

I finally stated that Delphi needs a pointer and will write data in it. So I gave `IntPtr`.

For the input/output parameters Pointers, I did this:

```cs
IntPtr pnt = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(oneOUTParameter));
Marshal.StructureToPtr(oneOUTParameter, pntForOneOUTParameter, false);
```

And called `FetchData(pntForINParameter, pntForOUTParameter, pntForOUTDetailParameter);`

Every time I end up with an error:

> Exception thrown at 0x004F0928 (DelphiDLL.dll) in DelphiDLLTest.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00002EE0.

Can you help me?

**EDIT**: Replace `ShortString` by `String`, and other types for the one in C#.

Comment: You can use Delphi debugger to debug your DLL and see exactly which line triggers the access violation. To debug the DLL, open the DLL project and in menu / run / parameters, put the C# executable in the host application field. When you'll hit F9 (Run with debugger) Delphi will launch the host application which in turn will load you DLL. When the access violation occurs, the debugger will break on the offending line.

Comment: Also, pay attention to field alignment in the records in both Delphi and C#. Look at the doc (https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Alexandria/en/Structured_Types_(Delphi)).

Comment: The declaration of FetchData correspond to an external function viewed from Delphi code. That is not what you are really using. The function should be exported by the DLL, not consumed. Maybe you took the declaration from a example of DLL use by another Delphi program. Show us the actual declaration in the DLL code.

Comment: Thank you fpiette for your answers.
I'm installing RADStudio from embarcadero website.

For the declaration of fetchdata. I could receive the dfm file of an application in delphi that use the dll.
I don't know really how to retrieve the actual declaration of the dll.

Comment: `//Delphi: SizeOf(TExcample) == 8
TExcample = packed record 
  Param1: integer;
  Param2: Longbool;
end;`

`//C#
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
 public struct Excample
 {
   [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
   public int  Param1;
   [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
   public bool Param2;
 }
`

Comment: You'll get the declaration from the DLL source code. And you also need the DLL source to recompile the DLL in Debug release so that the debugger can show the offending source code.

Comment: I don't have access to the source code, unfortunately.
And moreover, the company that developed this dll does not exists anymore :'(

Comment: Maybe the dll was compiled in debug release. I'm checking within minutes.

Comment: Unfortunately the dll was not compiled for debug..

Comment: @USauter the Delphi records don't appear to be packed. Why are you confusing the poor asker by assuming that they are?

Comment: So your real problem is the shortstring. This is actually a byte with the string length, and then 255 bytes of ANSI char. And your int array needs an attribute to declare its length. But your C# code doesn't compile so that's frustrating for us. What is public structure? Also what is Longint? And Boolean? These aren't C#. This is quite tractable, but you can't expect us to work with imprecise details.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to replace shortstring by string. That's what I did in my original code.
The code I gave you is a simplified version where you have all the structures (but with shorter name) used by FetchData. But I forgot to replace the shortstring by string in the simplified version.
I edit my post with the string.

Comment: To give you the whole explanation: In the begining it was done in vb.net.
But we found that you cannot do unsafe code in vb.net.
So we kept the types declaration in vb.Net, create a c# project for testing the dll and made a reference from c# project to that vb.net project containing the types.
To avoid confusing you, I rewrote the types that come from *.pas (in delphi) in c#. So you only have c# language.
But I already did those change in the vb.net version (i just forgot them) in the c# version.

Comment: What do you think I should have as declaration for FetchData in my C# application ?
So I'm sure at least to start working with something good.
Right now, i'm trying different signatures, without never knowing if it's the correct one to use.

Comment: I think you need to slow down. I know how to do pinvoke but I won't get into this question because I don't trust the code in the question. None of it seems real. I'd get Delphi and I'd learn how to do each type one by one in a test bed environment. There are probably 6 or 7 different issues with what is presented here and us attempting to solve them all will be fruitless. I've seen this question many times before!

Comment: Thank you David for your effort.
I can understand that you don't want to spend time on this question, because of the way I formulated it.
I'm not used to delphi and interop. I tried to give the best explanation and the extracted a sample from my ongoing work.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Who knows how the switch {$CODEALIGN n} were set [Code align (Delphi)](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Code_align_(Delphi)). By using Packed Record I don't get involved with this question at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see some interop problems in your code:

- raw pointers like `PInfo1` and `PInfo2` are not used in C#, so replace them with `IntPtr`.
- `string` in Delphi is very different than `string` in C#.  In Delphi, a `string` is a pointer to the character data, so you would have to use `IntPtr` on the C# side.  If you need to read from a `string` field that Delphi has allocated, you can simply use `Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi()` (Delphi 2007 or earlier) or `Marshal.PtrToStringUni()` (Delphi 2009 or later). But, if you need to pass in a `string` that Delphi will read, good luck.  You will have to manually allocate memory for not only the character data, but also the [`StrRec`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.UnicodeString.StrRec) record that precedes the character data (and the contents of that record can vary depending on Delphi version).  For this reason, passing `string` over the DLL boundary is a bad idea in interop.  You should instead use a flat `Char[]` array (or a `ShortString`), or a null-terminated `PChar` pointer.
- C# arrays are allocated dynamically, so when a fixed-sized array is contained in a `struct`, you need to use `MarshalAs` on the C# side to specify the size of the array.
- a `bool` in Delphi is 1 byte in size, but in C# interop a `bool` is marshalled as a 4-byte integer (a `LongBool` in Delphi) by default. You need to use `MarshalAs` to change that.
- a  Windows `LONG` is a 4-byte integer. A `Longint` in Delphi is 4 bytes in size on most platforms, but is 8 bytes in size on Posix 64bit systems. a `long` in C# is always 8 bytes.

With that said, the Delphi code you have shown would translate to something more like the following in C#:

```cs
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack=8)]
public struct Info1
{
    public byte Param1;
    public byte Param2;
    public byte Param3;
    public byte Param4;
    public int Param5;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack=8)]
public struct Info2
{
    public byte Param1;
    public int Param2;
    public int Param3;
    public int Param4;
    public int Param5; // long; use IntPtr or nint instead, if needed
    public IntPtr Param6; // string
    public int Param7;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst=9)]
    public int[] Param8;
    public IntPtr Param9; // string
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack=8)]
public struct INParameter
{
    public int Param1;
    public int Param2;
    public int Param3;
    public byte Param4;
    public byte Param5;
    public byte Param6;
    public byte Param7;
    public byte Param8;
    public byte Param9;
    public byte Param10;
    public byte Param11;
    public byte Param12;
    public byte Param13;
    public byte Param14;
    public byte Param15;
    public byte Param16;
    public byte Param17;
    public byte Param18;
    public byte Param19;
    public byte Param20;
    public byte Param21;
    public byte Param22;
    public int Param23;
    public int Param24;
    public byte Param25;
    public byte Param26;
    public byte Param27;
    public byte Param28;
    public byte Param29;
    public byte Param30;
    public byte Param31;
    public byte Param32;
    public int Param33;
    public IntPtr Param34; //PInfo1
    public IntPtr Param35; //PInfo2
}
  
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack=8)]
public struct OUTParameter
{
    public int Param1;
    public int Param2;
    public int Param3;
    public int Param4;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
    public bool Param5;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
    public bool Param6;
    public int Param7;
    public int Param8;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
    public bool Param9;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
    public bool Param10;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
    public bool Param11;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
    public bool Param12;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
    public bool Param13;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
    public bool Param14;
    public int Param15;
    public int Param16;
    public int Param17;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
    public bool Param18;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
    public bool Param19;
    public int Param20;
}
  
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack=8)]
public struct Pos
{
    public int Param1;
    public int Param2;
    public byte Param3;
    public byte Param4;
}
  
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack=8)]
public struct OUTDetails
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst=84)]
    public Pos[] Poss;
}

[DLLImport("DLL_Name", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
void FetchData(ref INParameter infoIn, ref OUTParameter infoOut, ref OUTDetails details);
```

Comment: Thanks.
It didn't worked with your code. But as you gave me a good start, I could focus on what was wrong.
I still had a read violation occuring, but it's due to PInfo1 and PInfo2.
I set those parameter to null and the call to the dll worked.
So now I need to investigate why it's not working there, but at least I have something running and not crashing.

Comment: This is the code which crash the dll, that I removed:

```
Info1 inf1 = new Info1();
                Info2 inf2 = new Info2();
                IntPtr info1Ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(inf1));
                IntPtr info2Ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(inf2));
                Marshal.StructureToPtr(inf1, info1Ptr, true);
                Marshal.StructureToPtr(inf2, info2Ptr, true);

                var inParam = new INParameter();
                inParam.Param34 = info1Ptr;
                inParam.Param35 = info2Ptr;
```

Comment: Without a marshaler, a C# bool in Delphi is a 4-byte LongBool instead of a 1-byte Boolean.

Comment: @USauter thanks. I always forget that (one of many reasons why I hate C# interop). I have updated my example